Flutter Web WebSocket Connection to Azure SignalR Hub: Passing Access Token After Negotiate
I'm wrestling with a SignalR authentication puzzle that's turning my hair gray
Scenario:

I have a SignalR service hosted on Azure

Previously worked fine with web_socket_channel in Flutter web when there was no authentication

Server recently added user authentication to the hub for map specific user

Mobile: Successfully passes access token via SignalR client's access token factory

Web: Using web_socket_channel package, stuck on token transmission
The curl of the negotiation step:
curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/chat-hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $accessToken'
Negotiate Response Looks Like:
{
    "negotiateVersion": 1,
    "connectionId": "hpCRJgUbCr7Y8x5UDCzhRA",
    "connectionToken": "OAtaVE1oEv4z0hceHAKhCg",
    "availableTransports": [
        {
            "transport": "WebSockets",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "LongPolling",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        }
    ]
}



The Burning Question: How do I inject the authentication access-token/connection-token when establishing a WebSocket connection for this SignalR endpoint on Flutter Web?
I've tried:

Appending accessToken to URL: ws://ctifiloops.bjitgroup.com:8088/chat-hub?access-token={{accessToken}}

Appending connectionToken to URL: ws://ctifiloops.bjitgroup.com:8088/chat-hub?id={{conncetionToken}}


Each attempt cannot connected with the authenticated user
Specific Constraints:

Using web_socket_channel

Azure SignalR Hub

Flutter Web targeting

Must authenticate per-connection

Access token available from login



blah.com/chat-hub?access_token={{accesstoken}}&id={{connectionToken}}
Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-9.0#built-in-jwt-authentication for handling auth token in the query string.

Thank you for your response. I'm using the SignalR client package for mobile devices, where the accessTokenFactory handles the access token seamlessly. However, for browsers, I need to negotiate before connecting to the server. If I implement the method you suggested, will it affect my existing mobile implementation?
@Brennan

The Code below is to Establish a WebSocket Connection to an Azure SignalR Hub in Flutter Web:
Make sure you enable WebSockets in your app service configurations.
Refer to this link for Authentication and Authorization in SignalR.
Refer to this link for details on how to communicate with WebSockets in Flutter.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'SignalR WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(title: title),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  WebSocketChannel? _channel;
  bool _isConnected = false;

  final String _signalRNegotiateUrl = "https://example.com/chat-hub/negotiate";
  final String _accessToken = "your-access-token-here";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _connectToSignalR();
  }

  Future<void> _connectToSignalR() async {
    try {
      final negotiateResponse = await _negotiate();

      if (negotiateResponse != null) {
        final connectionToken = negotiateResponse['connectionToken'];
        final webSocketUrl = _buildWebSocketUrl(negotiateResponse['url'], connectionToken);
        setState(() {
          _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(webSocketUrl));
          _isConnected = true;
        });

        _channel?.stream.listen(
          (message) {
            setState(() {
              print("Received: $message");
            });
          },
          onDone: () {
            setState(() {
              _isConnected = false;
            });
          },
          onError: (error) {
            setState(() {
              _isConnected = false;
              print("WebSocket error: $error");
            });
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error connecting to SignalR: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> _negotiate() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("$_signalRNegotiateUrl?negotiateVersion=1"),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_accessToken',
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        print("Negotiate failed: ${response.statusCode}, ${response.body}");
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Negotiate error: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }

  String _buildWebSocketUrl(String baseUrl, String connectionToken) {
    final uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
    return "${uri.replace(scheme: 'wss')}?id=$connectionToken";
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty && _isConnected) {
      _channel?.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel?.sink.close(status.normalClosure);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            _isConnected
                ? StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _channel?.stream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : 'No messages yet.');
                    },
                  )
                : const Text('Not connected to WebSocket.'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
    );
  }
}



In general, you connect to wss://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/chat-hub/negotiate and use https://your-signalr-hub-url/chat-hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1. For WebSocket transport, refer to this doc to configure it as follows:

 final url = Uri.parse('https://your-signalr-hub-url/chat-hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1');

  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    },
  );



Dear @Sampath,
When negotiating with an accessToken, the response includes a connectionId and connectionToken, but no URL is provided. However, when negotiating without an accessToken, a URL is included in the response.
Additionally, I noticed that using wss://xyz.com/hub-name?id=connectionID does not establish a connection with the specific user I intend to connect with.
